# How to create a list of years between two columns dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following layout in a data set:

[image]

I would like to have a formula which would print a list of the years from the start year to the end year in column B?

Any ideas on a formula that would achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if I'm missing something but =C2-A2 ?

Comment: Hi looking for a print of years, so in this case Output for B2 would be : 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Excel 365

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,C2-A2+1,A2))
```

working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need Office 365 for this, but then you could use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2+SEQUENCE(A2-C2-1))
```

After seeing your comment, you would have to use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2+SEQUENCE(A2-C2+1)-1)
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working. These values will be the YYYY of a date.

Comment: @DataProspector try again, I'm using a german machine and had the `;` separator instead of `,`

Comment: Getting "#VALUE!" output now.

Comment: What Excel-Version are you using?

Comment: Version 2104 on 365.